# Django - working with a 3rd party API along with pagination

Tags: python, django, api

Currently trying to learn Django. As a side project, I am trying to build a site that utilizes a 3rd party API. The user does a search, and my site displays photos based on that search once the search parameters are passed onto the 3rd party API and a response is received. The photos are displayed in a paginated manner.

The API itself gives me a result in the form of:

```
{
  page: 1
  pages: 60000
  photos: [...] //could contain anywhere from 10-100 items. Each item is a dict containing id, photo URL, as well other info
}
```

At the moment I have it set so that with each 'previous' or 'next' page, a new request is made to the API, after which the response could look like:

```
{
  page: 2
  pages: 60000
  photos: [...]
}
```

Of course, this isn't really ideal as it involves constantly making calls to the API. My question is: would it be bad practice to convert these items into django models and store them in my database? Considering the number of items that would have to be stored.

However, the advantage of having them in makes it easier to do things like 'liking' the photo, or things like that.

Note: I can cache the result, however the problem is that because it's looking up photos, and I need to perform functions on them like 'liking' or 'favoriting' the photo, storing in a cache doesn't work as I need it to persist.

Comment: At an API level, having a single call for a single user page load is unlikely to be perceived as excessive traffic, even with dozens of concurrent users. That said, if the data from the API does not change, or changes so infrequently that it'd be feasible to update your DB occasionally in the background, I'd consider that preferable. As far as 'liking,' though, you can persist those without local copies of the API data as long as the photo responses have some sort of static unique identifier.

Comment: The API data doesn't change. There may be new data coming from the API, but I could possibly set something up so that it only checks periodically. That said, it is still storing all that in the database. It's not a lot of data, basically just some text. But it still seems unnecessary.

My url for the photos list in /photos/. If I can persist a cache while the user is in /photos/, and then empty it out once the user leaves that URL, maybe that will work.

Comment: Worst case scenario: You rely on API requests for every single user visit. Their network conn has issues, your site has issues. API is down, your site is broken. None of this really changes much by complicating your life with a per-user, per-session cache. In your position I would definitely be keeping that data locally and refreshing it periodically. When removing a dependency -- _especially_ an external resource call -- is a realistic option, it's almost always a good idea. In your case it sounds like it would cost you basically nothing for a potentially significant reliability gain.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks, I'll store the data and occasionally refresh it. The only cost would be storage, but yes.. that would be worth it for the benefit it provides.